# REST API - Frontend testing

Tags: java, rest, selenium, backbone.js, frontend

Have frontend WebApplication developed in backbone which hits backend REST API in order to eg. download data from webservice to user interface table.

In Intellij have set maven project with two modules - one for functional selenium (webdriver/java) tests and second for rest.

What I am planning to do is to create under rest module some class which could call relevant rest API json method, put somewhere what was returned and under selenium module assert that with what ui table displays.  This is kind of integration test.

But ... this is theory , in real life have doubts if it could work like I've decribed and what should I use in order to download data from REST - I've been thinking about RestAssured or about SoapUI ...but maybe you could advise something what should be used (and how) ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with these kind of problem is :

1) Generate Java classes for your request and response json objects using below link
2) populate the request and call jersey api to populate response object.
3) once you get response object, create one more response oject by calling UI
4) Compare these two objects  and assert

Answer (score 0):

You may use Jasmine or Dredd for that.

Jasmine is a BDD oriented framework for javascript testing. It's very usefull for testing your javascript components, that includes calling your API throught your web framework.

Dredd offers more than that and a different approach, but it also may be used for that.

You can also use simple Java + Junit + Gson unit testing (even use some BDD framework like concordion) and you could also get the work done. Even using some RAML based tool.

Although they're not the same they could offer what you need. Other non framework based alternatives are fiddler, soapui.